# Is there a way to add custom permissions for web app user in azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

For instance, I have an application 'myApp' in app registrations and I have a user in Azure Active Directory `User1` which is an Admin in AD. I want to use authentication via Azure AD in that app and want `User1` to have a permissions only to access 'api/todos' and 'api/vehicles'. So there can be a role 'Role1`with permissions`Todos`,`Vehicles`. Is there a way to configure that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to configure that. Azure works with a Role concept. [This sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) shows how to do it in a web API.

In short: You need to define the possible roles and assign users to them via the application configuration in the admin portal. And then you need to define which roles the user should be in using the `[Authorize]` attribute, on the web API controller methods, e.g. like in [one of the sample's controllers](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/blob/master/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet/Controllers/TasksController.cs):

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Observer, Writer, Approver")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Tasks";
        ViewData["tasks"] = TasksDbHelper.GetAllTasks();
        return View();
    }
```

As usual with `[Authorize]` it is inherited, so you can put it on the entire controller class.

Comment: Ok, that is clear for me and I know about such possibility, what I m looking for is the way to add some configuration to that role, for example: role`admin` has permissions `readContacts`, `readTasks`. However, now I think that this info should be configured inside application and not Azure AD, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you would define the roles in AAD, and then your application determines which permissions a particular role should have.

Comment: agree, will do it in this way)